# Regex to find the files without .log extension and containing the filename report

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to find the all files in the current directory containing the name report and not ending with the extension .log
Is there any way I can use a regex to find the same in single go?

This is what I have came up with so far:

```
ls -la | grep ".*report*" | grep -v ".log"
```

But I was wondering if I can achieve the same something on the line like below

```
ls -l .*report*[^.log]
```

I know [^.log] won't filter out the files with .log extension, how to achieve the same using regex. I am using BASH btw. Thanks.

Comment: The shell doesn't support regexes outside of `[[ $a =~ $re ]]` expressions, so if you don't want to use external commands, you should be asking about glob patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an extglob for this. For instance:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
files=( report!(*.log) )
```

...for testing, of course, you can use `ls` (though it [shouldn't be used in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)):

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -l report!(*.log)
```

...will find all files starting with `report` but not ending in `.log`, and put their names in the array called `files`. Setting the `nullglob` option will prevent the pattern itself from being returned as a result if no files match.

You can then do something like the following to check the contents of the array:

```
if (( ${#files[@]} )); then
  echo "Found some files that need to be deleted!"
  rm -f "${files[@]}"
else
  echo "Nothing but .log files for the reports"
fi
```

This is an extended glob pattern (`shopt -s extglob` command turns them on; `shopt -u extglob` turns that extension back off again), not a regex. (Expressions like `*.log` are also glob patterns, not regexes; a similar regex would look like `.*[.]log`, and that's not what you use in shell).

Comment: Thanks but may be I am missing something log files are not filtered out.Please see the result below:[user1@fedora16a]$ shopt -s extglob
[user1@fedora16a]$ ls -l report*!(.log)
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user1 user1 0 Jul 23 16:14 report1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user1 user1 0 Jul 23 16:14 report2
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user1 user1 0 Jul 23 16:14 report3.log
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user1 user1 0 Jul 23 16:14 report4.log
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user1 user1 0 Jul 23 16:35 report.loge

Comment: @CppLearner Thanks for the feedback -- had to move the wildcard over a character, to be like so: `report!(*.log)`

Comment: This did the trick :) Thanks this is what I was looking for +1 and accepting as answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can say:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*report*" -a ! -name "*.log" \)
```

This would find files matching the pattern `report` and excluding files ending in `.log` in the current directory and all subdirectories.

If you want to find only in the current directory, you can say:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "*report*" -a ! -name "*.log" \)
```

Comment: wow,thanks. +1 for letting me know and for find. This is handy :) I was wondering if we can somehow combine the power of inclusion and negation via regex alone i.e. without using find

Comment: If you don't want to you `find`, you can adopt the approach suggested by @mishik.  However, `find` is much more powerful.

Answer (score 2):

If you will be driving a loop over these files anyway, it's trivial to skip the logs at the top of the loop.

```
for f in *report*; do
    case $f in *.log ) continue ;; esac
    :
    : do stuff with "$f" here
done
```

Notice that you should properly use `"$f"` in double quotes most everywhere, but after `case` they are not necessary.

Comment: +1 for 'for' perspective :). Though I was aware of the for loop syntax, its use in combination with case didn't came to my mind for solving my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
ls -ld !(*.log)
```

This will show all the files/dir in the current folder not ending with `.log`.

As far as I know, there is no way to filter both `include *report*` + `exclude .log`

So, in general, the cleanest approach would be:

```
ls -ald *report*  | grep -v '\.log'
```

Comment: +1, thanks for letting me know!() option and correctly wording "to filter both include *report* + exclude .log". I will wait for today to see if there is a tweak anyone aware of to do it in single go

Comment: The regex is wrong, though; you mean `grep -v '\.log$'`. The asterisk is a repetition postfix operator; postfixing nothing is invalid syntax, though many `grep` implementations will just silently ignore a leading `*`.

Comment: @tripleee +1 for pointing out my mistake as well. I was under impression that .log will actually search for .log, in reality it will search for any char followed by log. Good point of \. Thanks:)

Comment: You certainly can both filter for report and filter out `.log` with a single extglob. That said, you need to instruct the user to turn on extglobs (since they're off by default).